# Haskell program to remove comments

Tags: java, parsing, haskell, io, comments

I'm trying to write a Haskell program that takes a Java program (.java) and outputs it with all of its comments removed. The input does not have to be syntactically correct. I've set up the IO component to look like so:

```
main =
  do
     javaFile <- getFileName
     text <- readFile javaFile
     displayProgram ( AAAA )
     return ()
```

`AAAA` is the expression that takes the text and produces the new text with comments
removed. Notice that these functions are required:

```
getFileName :: IO [Char]
displayProgram :: [String] -> IO ()
```

I know the algorithm is pretty straightforward:

1. Search for `//` and remove that entire line of text.
2. Search for `/*` and remove all of the following text until you reach `*/` and remove `*/` as well. This should of course take care of both block comments and doc comments.
3. Output the remaining text.

However, Haskell is not one of my strongest languages. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What about String borked = "//";

Comment: Is this homework? If yes, please tag appropriately.

Comment: Your question is quite vague. What exactly do you need help with? `getFileName`? `displayProgram`? `AAAA`? If it's everything, you are better off reading some kind of Haskell tutorial.

Comment: It seems `language-java` could do exactly what you want, as its lexer eats all comments. Unfortunately, it chokes on comments within strings, and the lexer is Alex-generated code so it's a pain to fix that. But apart from that, I got it working with `readFile "whatever.java" Prelude.>>= print . show . pretty . either (error . show) id . parseCompilationUnit`, with `Prelude`, `Language.Java.Parser`, `Language.Java.Pretty` and `Data.Either` imported.

Answer (score 3):

Your algorithm is wrong: your search patterns may occur inside strings and your code needs to take that into account. The simplest example is a quine with comments:

```
package quine;
public class Quine {
   /**
    * This is a quine.
    */
   public static void main(String[] args) {
     String s1 = "package quine;\npublic class Quine {\n  /**\n   * This is a quine.\n   */\npublic static void main(String[] args) {\nString s1 = \"";
     // further code elided.
   }
}
```

Comment: I am lost why you chose an incomplete Quine to demonstrate that comment markers can be part of string literals and trip a simplistic algorithm to remove comments.

Comment: @HemalPandya I understand it as "the simplest example of why you would want to have Java comments inside a String". I don't think it's the simplest anyway :)

Comment: @Ptival how is Quine an example of why you would want to have comment inside string?

Comment: @Hemal Pandya: I chose a quine with comment because it is immediately obvious why there is a comment marker embedded in the string, and for a second reason: even if you did correctly strip only the comment itself (and not the stuff inside the string) you would still break the source code. (It would no longer be a quine, by definition.)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a function like that:

```
stripComments :: String -> String
stripComments [] = []
stripComments ('/':'/':xs) = inComment xs 
stripComments ('/':'*':xs) = inMultiComment xs
stripComments (x:xs) = x : stripComments xs
```

This will simply “loop“ through the string in a recursive manner (however, it’s tail recursive, thus it’s like a loop) and copy each char which is not within a comment.

The following functions are used to detect the end of a comment. They ignore any characters except for the ending delimiters, thus the underscore in the pattern match.

```
inComment :: String -> String
inComment ('\n':xs) = stripComments xs
inComment (_:xs) = stripComments xs
inComment [] = []

inMultiComment :: String -> String
inMultiComment ('*':'/':xs) = stripComments xs
inMultiComment (_:xs) = inMultiComment xs
inMultiComment [] = []
```

If you use more sophisticated parsing however I recommend taking a shot on the Parsec monadic parsing library.

EDIT: As user268396 pointed out you should be aware that something looking like a Comment may be hiding in a String. You might want to extend the above functions with a “inString” function which does *not* ignore the characters it encounters, yet does not switch to inComment or inMultiComment if it encounters starting delimiters for these.

Comment: Little typo in the third line:   
inComment (_:xs) = inComment xs

Answer (score 0):

As an example for something similar, see how I strip out comments, etc. from [Dot code](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/graphviz/2999.12.0.3/doc/html/src/Data-GraphViz-PreProcessing.html); note that I'm using combinators I've defined (but not fully commented) [here](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/graphviz/2999.12.0.3/doc/html/Data-GraphViz-Parsing.html) for use with the Text parser in PolyParse.

It doesn't consider comments in Strings, etc., but **does** remove all comments of the form using `/* ... */` and `// ...`

Answer (score 0):

3 implementation approaches are possible:

- manual pattern matching on Strings
- using Text.Parsec package
- using Text.Regex package

For a homework, I'd go with manual matching
For a robust implementation, I'd go with Text.Parsec
For a quick and dirty solution, I'd go with Text.Regex

Answer (score 0):

```
stripComments :: String -> String
stripComments [] = []
stripComments ('/':'/':xs) = inComment xs 
stripComments ('/':'*':xs) = inMultiComment xs
stripComments ('\"':xs) = '\"' : inString xs
stripComments (x:xs) = x : stripComments xs

inComment :: String -> String
inComment [] = []
inComment ('\n':xs) = stripComments xs
inComment (_:xs) = inComment xs

inMultiComment :: String -> String
inMultiComment [] = []
inMultiComment ('*':'/':xs) = stripComments xs
inMultiComment (_:xs) = inMultiComment xs

inString :: String -> String
inString [] = []
inString ('\"':xs) = '\"' : stripComments xs
inString (x:xs) = x : inString xs
```